# sqlserver stored procedure with laravel returns true value

Tags: sql-server, laravel, stored-procedures

I am new to store procedure and laravel . 
My table in form of script is as follows

```
create table SiveUsuarios
(
ID_Usuario         int identity
constraint PK_Usuarios
primary key,
Login              varchar(15),
Clave              varchar(50),
Password           varchar(191),
Nombre             varchar(50),
Accesos            varchar(200),
Estado             int,
Canal              varchar(30),
Distribuidora      varchar(50),
TipoUsuario        varchar(25),
FechaActualizacion varchar(23)
)
go
```

I have one query which is as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pa_AnadeUsuario]
@Login AS VARCHAR(15) = '',
@Nombre AS VARCHAR(50) = '',
@Clave AS VARCHAR(15) = '',
@PASSWORD AS VARCHAR(191) = '',
@Accesos AS VARCHAR(200) = '',
@Estado AS INT = 0,
@Canal AS VARCHAR(30) ='',
@Distribuidora AS VARCHAR(50) = '',
@TipoUsuario AS VARCHAR(25) = '',
@Retorno AS INT = 0 OUTPUT,
@FechaActualizacion AS VARCHAR(23) = '' OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @Fecha AS VARCHAR(23)
DECLARE @Error AS INT

SET @Fecha = CONVERT (VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO SiveUsuarios (Login,Password, Nombre, Clave, Accesos, 
Estado, Canal, Distribuidora, TipoUsuario, FechaActualizacion)
VALUES (@Login, @PASSWORD,@Nombre, @Clave, @Accesos, @Estado, @Canal, 
@Distribuidora, @TipoUsuario, @Fecha)
SELECT @Error = @@ERROR, @Retorno = @@IDENTITY


/* CONTROL DE ERRORES. */
IF @Error = 0
BEGIN
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  SET @FechaActualizacion = @Fecha
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
go
```

And here is my laravel code for calling the store procedure

```
    $user=DB::select('exec  pa_AnadeUsuario @Login= :login,
                                               @Nombre= :nombre,
                                               @Clave= :clave,
                                               @PASSWORD= :password,
                                               @Accesos= :accesos,
                                               @Estado= :estado,
                                               @Canal= :canal,
                                        @Distribuidora=:distribuidora,
                                               @TipoUsuario = :tipo
                                               ',[
        'login'=>1,
        'nombre'=>2,
        'clave'=>3,
        'password'=>4,
        'accesos'=>5,
        'estado'=>6,
        'canal'=>7,
        'distribuidora'=>8,
        'tipo'=>9
    ]);
```

But I am able to execute the code but the value of user is returned as true .

Can anyone help me with this error.
Any help will be appreciated . Thanks .